# Examples of a topological semidirect product

Tags: gn.general-topology, examples, topological-groups, automorphism-groups, automorphisms

Let $G$ be a compact topological group, and $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ the group of autohomeomorphisms of $G$. I have proved some (topological) results about the holomorph $G\leftthreetimes \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, and now looking for nice examples.

I can, of course, take any compact group $G$, but I want to know if there are "natural" examples to be found. That is, are there any compact groups $G$ for which the semidirect product $G\leftthreetimes \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is of a particular interest?

Thank you!

Comment: Is that really the notation people use for the topological semi-direct product? I've never seen this symbol used as an operation.

Comment: Automorphisms, you mean? (if you only assume homeos, the semi-direct product makes no sense...)

Comment: @DavidWhite : yes, this is the notation people use, as far as I know. See, for example, this recent survey http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~megereli/DMsurveyFinal.pdf

Comment: @AlainValette: I mean automorphisms that are also homeomorphisms.

Comment: OK, continuous automorphisms, then! You could look at cases where $Aut(G)$ is large, e.g. $G=C_2^\mathbb{N}$, where $C_2$ is the 2-element group.

Comment: @AlainValette Thanks, but can you please elaborate? What makes $G\leftthreetimes Aut(G)$ interesting, for the $G$ you offered?

Comment: In this case $Aut(G)$ is large, as it contains e.g. the full symmetric group of the integers. And presumably you view the semi-direct product $G\rtimes Aut(G)$ as interesting (BTW, $\rtimes$ is the notation in group theory), since you prove results about it.